# ngCordova datepicker with ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, datetimepicker, ngcordova

I am trying to implement the ngCordova datePicker plugin for my app.  The link to the plugin is here, http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/datePicker/.  The implementation is running perfectly in the IOS simulator, but I can't get anything to happen on android.  I get the same error that I do in the browser saything the plugin show function cannot be called.  I have searched all the pages on the stack and google for the issue.  Nothing I have found has given a clear solution to the issue.  Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the template html

```
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="getDate()">
     Date: {{date | date:'MMMM, dd'}}
</button>
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="getTime()">
     Date: {{date | date:'h:mma'}}
</button>
```

Here are my dependency injections

```
function($scope, $state, $timeout, $cordovaDatePicker, $ionicPlatform, $q)
```

Here is the the plugin function calls

```
var now = new Date();
now.setMinutes(get15MinBlock());
$scope.date = now;
$scope.eventInfo.when.date = $scope.date;
$scope.getDate = function() {
    var dateOptions = {
        date: $scope.date,
        mode: 'date', // or 'time'
        allowOldDates: false,
        allowFutureDates: true,
        doneButtonLabel: 'DONE',
        doneButtonColor: '#F2F3F4',
        cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
        cancelButtonColor: '#000000'
    };
    dateOptions.date = $scope.date;
    $q.when($cordovaDatePicker.show(options)).then(function(date){
        $scope.date.setMonth(date.getMonth());
        $scope.date.setDate(date.getDate());
        $scope.eventInfo.when.date = $scope.date;
        return;
    }, function(error) { // Android only
        alert('Error: ' + error);
    });
};
$scope.getTime = function() {
    var allowOldDates = false;
    if (($scope.date.getMonth() > new Date().getMonth()) || ($scope.date.getDate() > new Date().getDate())) {
        console.log('Allowed');
        allowOldDates = true;
    }
    var timeOptions = {
        date: $scope.date,
        mode: 'time', // or 'time'
        allowOldDates: allowOldDates,
        allowFutureDates: true,
        doneButtonLabel: 'DONE',
        doneButtonColor: '#F2F3F4',
        cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
        cancelButtonColor: '#000000',
        minuteInterval: 15
    };
    timeOptions.date = $scope.date;
    $q.when($cordovaDatePicker.show(timeOptions)).then(function(time){
        $scope.date.setHours(time.getHours());
        $scope.date.setMinutes(time.getMinutes());
        $scope.eventInfo.when.date = $scope.date;
        return;
    }, function(error) {
        alert('Error: ' + error);
    });
};
```

This is the error I receive in chrome://inspect on my android device.
[image]

Comment: have you injected `$cordovaDatePicker` in your controller?

Comment: Yes,  I forgot to add that to the post.  One minute.